# Why do we use the singular in a comparative sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number

In a comparative sentence, like the one below, we use the singular form in the second clause:

> Rebecca is the most beautiful girl in the school. She is more beautiful than any other **girl**

and not:

> *[...] She is more beautiful than any other **girls**.

Why do we use the singular and not the plural? Why is the second example not acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "any other" construction takes the singular because the comparison is **one-to-one**.

> She is more beautiful than any other **girl**.

is equivalent to:

> She is more beautiful than any other individual **girl**.

You could express a similar sentiment with a construction that takes the plural "girls" like so:

> She is more beautiful than other **girls**.

But this works because, in this case, the comparison is **one-to-many**.

In short:  as an adjective in this case, 'any' can take the singular

Comment: You could also drop *all* in the plural example. "...than other girls."

Comment: True. I suppose I was just trying to follow suit with adding 'individual' to the 'any' example, so to be explicit about things. I'll update to make more clear.

Answer (score -1):

*Rebecca* is singular, therefore *girl* is singular.

The following is grammatical:

**Rebecca** is more beautiful than any other **girls** I know.*

For instance:

[*My friend shreds harder than any other **girls** I know.*](http://www.reddit.com/r/longboarding/comments/1ev7q2/)

And, If you change the wording, then the following is acceptable:

**Rebecca** is more beautiful than any of the other **girls.**

Thus, I am not convinced that the following *is* ungrammatical:

**Rebecca** is more beautiful than any other **girls**.

---

In addition, you can use plurals in comparatives:

“[Jersey girls have this inner glow that makes them more beautiful than any other girls.](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/412303-jersey-girls-have-this-inner-glow-that-makes-them-more)”

**Jersey girls** is a plural subject; therefore the plural girls is compared to the plural **(any) other girls.**

You probably will not run into **Girls (plural)** are more beautiful than **any other girl (singular).**

Comment: You can say "Rebecca is more beautiful than other girls"! Read the other answer: it doesn't have anything to do with Rebecca/she but how the comparison is formed.